# Splitting unformatted date/time string and assign to individual variables to concatenate

Tags: python

I have tried to make this input date and time structure...

```
core.setDate("19411213T1234","UTC");
```

(note the "T" in the middle)

...into this...

```
core.setDate("1941-12-13T12:34:00","UTC");
```

I tried to use the splitdate(), but the "T" did not allow the function to produce the correct output. It was my intention to locate the start of the string with "content.find" assigning the cut-up strings to individual variables. FYI - the end two letters are "st" which references the beginning of the found position and "nd" references the end position. I hope this makes sense?

Here is the code I have been working with...

```
# Initial Opening of "startup.ssc" for writing.
stella = open(""+stellocation+"\\scripts\\startup.ssc",'w')

# Write raw Date and Time line
stella.write(f'core.setDate("{date}T{time}:00","UTC");\n')

# Initial close of startup.ssc for safety
stella.close()

#Reopening of startup.ssc
stella = open(""+stellocation+"\\scripts\\startup.ssc",'w')

# Format raw Date and Time line
startdatetime = content.find("core.setDate")
yearst = content.find("(\"",startdatetime)
yearnd = content.find("",startdatetime+4)
monthst = content.find("",yearnd)
monthnd = content.find("",monthst+2)
dayst = content.find("",monthnd)
daynd = content.find("",dayst+2)
hourst = content.find("",daynd+1)
hournd = content.find("",hourst+2)
minutest = content.find("",hournd)
minutend = content.find("",minutest+2)

# Write Formatted Date and Time line
stella.write(f'core.setDate("{yearnd}-{monthnd}-{daynd}T{hournd}:{minutend}:00","UTC");\n')
```

Instead of producing the output I showed above, the code produces this errant text...

```
core.setDate("3-5-7T10:12:00","UTC");
```

I don't know why?

Comment: Hi Martineau - FMI, why did you edit my title? I'd like to know so I can keep your guidance in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
def reformat(d):
    return f'{d[:4]}-{d[4:6]}-{d[6:11]}:{d[11:13]}:00'


print(reformat("19411213T1234"))
```

Comment: Thanks DarkKnight - it works, but I don't understand why? I understand the need to break the string down, but I don't understand why solution works. Can you please direct me to a pertinent link I can study?

Comment: There's useful information on string slicing here:- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Thank you. It has taken me a few hours to digest the Python docs and your solution, but it finally clicked. 